# jackson - MessageBodyWriter Not Found when returning a JSON POJO from a GET Api

Tags: java, json, jersey, jackson, jax-rs

I was trying to return a simple json response using jackson.

```
@GET
    @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public FMSResponseInfo test(){
        System.out.println("Entered the function");
        FMSResponseInfo fmsResponseInfo = new FMSResponseInfo();
        List<SearchDetailsDTO> searchDetailsDtoList = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            SearchDetailsDTO searchDetailsDto = new SearchDetailsDTO();
            searchDetailsDto.setBarcode("barcode" + i);
            searchDetailsDto.setDocNo("docNo" + i);
            searchDetailsDto.setDocType("docType" + i);
            searchDetailsDtoList.add(searchDetailsDto);
        }
        fmsResponseInfo.setStatus("200");
        fmsResponseInfo.setMessage("Success");
        fmsResponseInfo.setData(searchDetailsDtoList);
        System.out.println("Exiting the function");
        return fmsResponseInfo;
    }
```

This is the code. When the function tries to return the FMSResponseInfo which is POJO :

```
package com.fms.core;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonInclude;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonPropertyOrder;
@JsonInclude(JsonInclude.Include.NON_NULL)
@JsonPropertyOrder({ "status", "message", "data" })
public class FMSResponseInfo {
    @JsonProperty("status")
    private String status;
    @JsonProperty("message")
    private String message;
    @JsonProperty("data")
    private Object data;
    //Getters and Setters
}
```

This is the pojo which will be sent back.

But as soons as the function tries to return this , I get this exception :

> May 14, 2015 9:54:57 AM
>   org.glassfish.jersey.message.internal.WriterInterceptorExecutor$TerminalWriterInterceptor
>   aroundWriteTo SEVERE: MessageBodyWriter not found for media
>   type=application/json, type=class com.fms.core.FMSResponseInfo,
>   genericType=class com.fms.core.FMSResponseInfo.

I have included jackson-annotation-2.4.2.jar, jackson-core-2.4.2.jar and jackson-databind-2.4.2.jar. These are the three jackson jars I have included along with the other jars required by jersey 2.16 and hibernate and mysql.

Please help me resolve this issue !!

Comment: do I need any other jar ???

Comment: Hi, did you add the ` <artifactId>jersey-media-json-jackson</artifactId>` according to https://jersey.java.net/documentation/2.16/media.html#json.jackson ?

Answer (score 1):

You need more than just Jackson, you need the Jackson JAX-RS provider.

[image]

Then register it either in web.xml

```
<init-param>
    <param-name>jersey.config.server.provider.packages</param-name>
    <param-value>
        your.resource.provider.package,
        com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json
    </param-value>
</init-param>
```

Or in your `ResourceConfig`

```
packages("your.resource.provider.packgae",
         "com.fasterxml.jackson.jaxrs.json");
```